# Use extension and normal attributes together in xsd

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to make mapping and i need to use:

- Config.xxx.yyy.KeyPair[z].normalAttribute
- Config.xxx.yyy.KeyPair[z]@extendAttribute

*KeyPair could be used from 0 to x times*

- Extra attribs: KeyId, KeyType, ValidTo, Active
- Normal attribs: PrivateKey, PublicKey

But error is thrown when i'm trying to load xsd file in C#:

```
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.
```

Here is shown shorten version how i made it, but it doesn't work at all:

```
<xs:element name="Config">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="xxx">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="EncryptionKeys" type="yyy"/>
          </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="yyy">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="KeyPair" type="KeyPairExtraTypes" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="KeyPairAttributes"/>
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="KeyPairExtraTypes"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:attributeGroup name="KeyPairAttributes">
  <xs:attribute name="PrivateKey" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="PublicKey" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:complexType name="KeyPairExtraTypes">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="KeyId"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="KeyType" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ValidTo" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:bool" name="Active" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: It won't work at all because `yyy` is an element name so you can't refer to it as a type. I don't know if that's the essence of the problem or just incidental. You really haven't explained properly what you want to achieve: it's very hard to reverse-engineer requirements from non-working code.

Comment: I'll add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easy.

```
<xs:element name="Config">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="xxx">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="EncryptionKeys">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="KeyPair" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:all>
                                                <xs:element name="PublicKey" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="PrivateKey" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:all>
                                            <xs:attribute name="KeyId"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="KeyType" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="ValidTo" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Active" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```